# How to switch classes with same name and different namespaces?

Tags: java, c#, design-patterns

I have read the blog post [Repository Design Pattern](https://medium.com/@krzychukosobudzki/repository-design-pattern-bc490b256006)

The main idea of the article is to cast classes with same name to get more functionality. It's ok, I understand it. But i can't understand this code:

```
repository.query(new NewestNewsesSpecification());
```

He has `NewestNewsesSpecification` for sql and `NewestNewsesSpecification` for Realm.

So my question - how the program can understand what implementation of `NewestNewsesSpecification`  to use, if classes have the same name but in different namespaces? It's not even a DI framework. Or is it just that every time I need different storage I need to find and change namespaces in source code files?

The code of article is in Java. I'm writing in C#.

Comment: This defeats the entire purpose of interfaces, frankly.  In my opinion, when you start casting, you're adding danger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read the article very quickly. He is explaining the Repository Pattern. This helps to encapsulate implementation details of the actual used repository. This way you can swap underlying repositories without modifying your client code. The underlying details are encapsulated in the `Specification` class. You have to explicitly pass an implementation of this base class to the repository e.g. into the 'query' method. This is the point where you the client have to decide which repository to use (or to query) by creating the appropriate instance.

If you have multiple implementations sharing the same name then they are required to reside in a different namespace to avoid ambiguities. You are right if you assume that the compiler can't resolve this colliding references. Usually you have to fully qualify the type (e.g instantiation, cast): 'new Sql.NewestNewsesSpecification()' or use the compiler directive 'using' or 'import' to declare the appropriate namespace so that the short form can be used: 'new NewestNewsesSpecification()'. The article assumes that you include either 'Sql' namespace or the 'Realm' namespace. Main idea was, my guess, to show which parts of code will change when replacing the underlying repository (the context). If you include both namespaces simultaneously, you can specify an alias for one of the implementations or use fully qualified references so that the references are not ambiguous any more.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Now i know i understand all it correct! But what if i dont want not to replace namespaces at using section when i need to use other specification class. How can i just switch it  fast (maybe at config part)? Even with IoC i cant uderstand how to make it.

Comment: You can switch it by creating an instance of the right Specification class implementation. You always have to fully qualify the type you are using. This means you have to point to type by using the full path to it. This means you have to walk from package or assembly to the type. Usually the package is resolved under the hood by adding a reference to the project it contains. Inside this package you have namespaces that contain types. You have to show the compiler or linker where to look for the type so that it can be resolved.

Comment: If you don't like to use an alias I recommend to give each subtype a distinct name: e.g. NewestNewsesSqlSpecification and NewestNewsesRealmSpecification. This makes it also clear what this type is specialized for.

Comment: The same applies to any IOC. It must be configured accordingly. That means you also have define which concrete implementation to load for an abstract type. For it's the compilers responsibility to resolve the types, you still have to provide the full path to the type or use the short form by using the 'using' directive.

Comment: Thanks. So your main idea - if i write much code, where i use concreate instances (for sql, for example) and then i want to switch to xml, i need to edit each file. So if i want to edit only one time i can load just assembly. Right?

Comment: Excuse me, but I am not sure if I understand you right. You have this 'Repository' class. Each time you want to query this repository using the 'Query(Specification)' method you have to pass an instance of the underlying context (or specification). If you want to switch between specifications, next time you query the repository just use the other 'Specification' implementation: 'result = Repository.Query(sqlSpecification)' becomes 'result = Repository.Query(xmlSpecification)'.

Comment: Any time you are using a concrete class by calling the constructor 'IConcreteType instance = new ConcreteType()' you have to modify this lines e.g. to become 'IConcreteType instance = new OtherConcreteType()'. If you don't want to modify all those places where you called a constructor, use a factory to encapsulate type instantiation instead. So instead of calling 'new ConcreteType()' you call 'SpecificationFactory.CreateSpecification()'. You now only have to modify the factory. Or use a Dependency Injection framework.

Comment: Ok, sorry, ill try to explain.  I have, DAL, BAL in my project. its separated layers. For now i use Mysql, that have table "Friends [id, name, second_name]"; In my bussiness layer i want to get all my friends - so i need some "IFriendsRepository" . As i mentioned i use mysql, so i have MysqlFriendsRepository. Ok.  I  use it but i dont create concrete IFriendsRepository class, i get instance from constructor of my business layer class by IoC. So for my IoC i setted IFriendsRepository - MysqlFriendsRepository. So code is totally solid.

Comment: So my  "IFriendsRepository" has method public List<Friends> GetByQuery(I Specification specification). So in my BAL class i have -  List<Friends> friends = _friendRepository.GetByQuery(DAL.Specifications.Mysql.GetOnlyWomenSpecification). But as u can see i use total namespace DAL.Specifications.Mysql.GetOnlyWomenSpecification.

Comment: Thats a problem. If i want to switch MysqlFriendsRepository to FileFriendsRepository i can do it easy by making new IoC Settings.But my code will not work because my BAL have "DAL.Specifications.Mysql.GetOnlyWomenSpecification" inside. But i need "DAL.Specifications.File.GetOnlyWomenSpecification". So i need edit every file by using Ctrl + R; Its not ok. What if i have 12 specifications or more. It can take so much time to edit. But i want just edit only one setting file and my program must work good. Hope u can understand what im saying.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your situation a little more. i think now understand your problem. I think you are using DI wrong (at least in this place). Your BAL class needs a constructor that accepts a 'Specification' instance (or the abstract base type of 'GetOnlyWomenSpecification' to be precise). Then you have to configure your DI Container to instantiate your BAL class using the proper concrete type. Make sure that all concrete implementations share the same base class. Same means the one that is shared independent from the namespace that you are referencing (e.g. namespace called Shared).

Comment: Now when you want to change the context of your repository you only have to modify configuration of your DI container. So inside your BAL class you don't know about any concrete 'GetOnlyWomenSpecification'. You only know or use its abstraction (e.g. 'Specification').

Comment: Because 'File.GetOnlyWomenSpecification' is a 'Specification' and 'Mysql.GetOnlyWomenSpecification' is a 'Specification you can substitute each one with the other or any other 'Specification' implementation. Did I get you right?

Comment: In general, when using DI don't use concrete implementations anywhere in your code except for library types, where you have to. This eliminates DI. Always use interfaces or abstract classes in method signatures or member declarations. Concrete types appear only in your DI container. See Dependency Inversion Principle (the 'I' in SOLID) if you don't know it. It's important to use it throughout your code and fundamental to of DI. So this kind of problems can't occur and your application remains extensible.

Comment: Yeah thank u very much. You are totally right. Ok i think u have much expirience and can answer for this too: If in my bal i have only one Specification so i can use IoC to set concrete class. Its ok. But i thought to implement this technique.

Comment: "Query query = new Query(); query.Add(ConcrSqlSpec1).Add(ConcreteSqlSpe2).Add(ConcreteSqlSpec3)". And after i make "List<Friends> = _repository.Find(query);"   So i want to switch sql storage to xml. I can switch MysqlFriendsRepository to XmlFriendsRepository by IoC. But as u can see in my code i have problems with Specs.   I need to rewrite it. How can i solve it?

Comment: You have to inject a factory into the context that is using the 'Query' object. Follow the Abstract Factory Pattern. Code would look like 'query.Add(factory.CreateSpec1).Add(factory.CreateSpec2)' where factory is of type e.g. 'ISpecificationFactory'. In your dependency container, when changing to XmlFriendsRepository, you have to change the concrete factory type too: from 'SqlRepositorySpecFactory' to 'XmlRepositorySpecFactory'. That's how to inject the proper 'ISpecificationFactory' implementation. Thus you would have two factory implementations or in general a factory for each Repository.

Comment: Use Dependency Inversion and Abstract Factories. If you do so you won't have this kind of problems.

Comment: Thank u buddy. I really appreciate it. U helped me a lot!